# sh does not take $PATH into account

Tags: shell, path

This works

```
sh /opt/gap-4.11.1/bin/gap.sh
```

This does not work

```
sh gap.sh
```

and returns error message

```
sh: 0: Can't open gap.sh
```

But the required directory is in `$PATH`, as confirmed with `echo $PATH`

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/gap-4.11.1/bin
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5):

While POSIX allows `sh` implementations to look `file` up in `$PATH` upon `sh file` when `file` is not found in the current working directory, as that's what `ksh` (on a subset of which the `sh` specification is based) does, it doesn't require it and most `sh` implementations nowadays don't (even `mksh` doesn't) as that's not desirable.

The fact that POSIX allows it and that some implementations do actually causes the reverse problem:

```
sh -- "$file"
```

Is not guaranteed by POSIX to interpret the file whose path is stored in `$file`, so you have to do:

```
case $file in
  ('') echo >&2 error;;
  (*/*) sh -- "$file";;
  (*) sh "./$file";;
esac
```

portably to work around it.

That's also why you see people use:

```
sh ./file
```

When they want to make sure it's the `file` in the current directory that is interpreted and not run the risk of interpreting some completely unrelated script in `$PATH` if `file` happens to be missing, just like you do `./ls` to  run the `ls` command in the current working directory instead of the one in `$PATH`.

There is a similar problem with the `.` utility which does a `$PATH` lookup when `$file` doesn't contain a `/`. While POSIX doesn't allow falling back to interpreting the file in the current directory if it can't be found in `$PATH`, bash or zsh when not in sh mode do. `csh`' equivalent to `.`: `source` does not do a `$PATH` lookup. In `zsh`, `source` falls back to a `$PATH` lookup. In `bash`, `source` behaves like `.`.

Here, as your script is in `$PATH`, and assuming you have execute permission for it, you can just enter:

```
gap.sh
```

For `gap.sh` to be looked up in `$PATH`. If the script has no shebang, it should be interpreted by a POSIX `sh` compliant interpreter.

If you have read but not execute permission, you can do:

```
sh -c '. gap.sh' sh arguments for gap.sh
```

Which as seen above will do a `$PATH` lookup.

As a history note, upon `ksh file`, `ksh` used to do the `$PATH` lookup first. That was a security vulnerability on systems that supported setuid scripts as you could do:

```
ln -s /path/to/some/setuid/ksh/script /tmp/file
echo sh > ~/bin/file
PATH=$PATH:~/bin
cd /tmp
```

And invoke `exec("file", ...)` which with a `#! /bin/ksh -` shebang would become  `/bin/ksh - file` run as the setuid user and `ksh` would end up interpreting `~/bin/file` instead of `/tmp/file`, so you'd get a root shell if the script was setuid root.

Answer (score 2):

`PATH` will be taken into account for the program being executed, in this case `sh`.

As `/bin:/opt/gap-4.11.1/bin` is in your `PATH`, you should be able to run it "directly", running:

```
gap.sh
```

as long as it has execute permission.